# How do I change the LabelStyle for all graphics producing functions programmatically (only for the current session)

Tags: plotting, code-request

I want to change the default label style (or every Font appearing in graphics if easier) programmatically for the current session. Specifically I want to change the color to black (from the default grey).

For a single plot this can be done by specifying `LabelStyle -> Black`. One might hope that the same method that works for some other settings such as `ImageSize` also works for other options (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228506/45020). However, the following does nothing:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 GraphicsBoxOptions -> {"LabelStyle" -> Black}]
```

The reason is probably the one explained in [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36770/45020](http://this%20answer). I tried implementing the solution from there but I fail at changing the stylesheet appropriately (let alone doing it programmatically).

[The other solution to that question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36774/45020) is programmatical but for some reason it fails to change the FontColor. (It does work in all other ways.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) as follows:

```
$PrePrint = If[MemberQ[{Graphics, Graphics3D}, Head@#], 
    Show[#, LabelStyle -> {24, FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS", Red}], #] &;

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> "LABEL"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the current notebook's style sheet:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> Cell[StyleData["GraphicsLabel"], Black]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might have unforeseen downsides but one way is to add a definition for `Graphics` itself. Something like:

```
Unprotect[Graphics];
Graphics[any__]/;FreeQ[{any},LabelStyle]:=Graphics[any,LabelStyle->Black];
```